# Difference between two files with same content

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have two files with identical content, but with different names, DateTimeCreation etc.

How do I calculate md5 hash only of a content (md5 hash of files are  different) ?

I need this to search for duplicates of files.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+md5+file+contents

Comment: @SLaks Thx! Everything works as i wanted